# Python change class functions

Tags: python, class

In Python, is it possible to take a class and remove one of its member functions? i.e.: Class A has 7 member functions. Five other classes inherit from class A. Now, say one of those classes doesn't want one of class A's member functions. Is there a way to keep that function fron showing up?

Comment: Sounds more like you need to reconsider your implementation / design than muck with an existing implementation

Comment: Agreed, this isn't supported specifically in Python because you shouldn't be doing it in the first place!

Comment: @jamylak the problem is that the top answer there is actually wrong...

Comment: @JBernardo Shouldn't we be fixing it on that page then?

Comment: @JBernardo: While that question's answer doesn't really remove the method, overriding a method to raise an exception is probably the most appropriate way to say that part of an inherited interface is off limits in a subclass. I'd not use `AttributeError` though, but something more descriptive (with a message explaining why the interface was different in the subclass).

Comment: @Blckknght the propose of removing the method is not the best one, but it's not hard to raise `AttributeError` with a `property`. Having the function call to return something will require a signature compatible with the parent one. Even setting the name to `None` seems better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, say one of those classes doesn't want one of class A's member
>   functions. Is there a way to keep that function fron showing up?

The [__dir__ method](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#dir) lets you control which methods "show-up".  It doesn't disable the method, it just allows you to control what is seen.

Ideally, that effort should be accompanied by overriding the method in question and having it raise [*NotImplementedError*](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.NotImplementedError) (for example, this is the approach used in Python's [*collections.Counter.fromkeys()*](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/0c308d65d7bc/Lib/collections.py#l490) method.

Depending on the method, there are other ways of disabling it.  For example, an inherited __hash__ method can be disabled by setting it to *None* (for example this is the approach using in the collections abstract base classes such as [*collections.Mapping*](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/0c308d65d7bc/Lib/_abcoll.py#l225)).

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you shouldn't remove part of a base class's API in a subclass. That's because one of the points of inheritance is that instances of the subclasses *are* instances of the base class. If they are missing methods, stuff may break in awkward ways.

That said, it is occasionally appropriate to override an inherited method and to raise an exception if the call is inappropriate. This might be only if the arguments are not what the subclass needs, but in some cases it might be appropriate for all calls. Try to make the exception helpful though, as it would be no fun for a programmer to get an unexpected `AttributeError` or other common error when calling a documented method.

Here's an example of a subclass that overrides part of its superclass's API to forbid its use. Note that I'm using getter and setter methods, which is generally not very Pythonic, but easy to understand (better is to use `property`s).

The base class:

```
class Rectangle(object):
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self._width = width
        self._height = height

    def get_width(self):
        return self._width

    def set_width(self, value):
        self._width = value)

    def get_height (self):
        return self._height 

    def set_height (self, value):
        self._height = value)

    def area(self):
        return self.get_width() * self.get_height()
```

And a subclass:

```
class Square(Rectangle):
    def __init__(self, side):
        self._side = side

    def get_side(self):
        return self._side

    def set_side(self, value):
        self._side = value

    get_width = get_height = get_side

    def set_width(self, value):
        raise TypeError("Squares cannot have their sides changed individually")

    set_height = set_width
```

The `area` method is inherited and still works as expected in the `Square` class, as will other code for Rectangles that only calls an instance's getter methods, not the setter methods.